# Send Data From Central To Peripheral

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbcentralmanager

I'm developing an app using BTLE iOS. I want to send data from central to peripheral without delay. 
As of now i can received the data coming from the peripheral, and also i send data from central to peripheral. I have  four data to be send:
     1. @"I:A:O\n";
     2. @"I:A:1\n";
     3. @"I:B:O\n";
     4. @"I:B:1\n";
sending "A" value has a delay in first send by 2-3 seconds. sending "B" value has a delay in second send 2-3 seconds. and then sometimes it is not working.

There is the code that receive and send data

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error discovering characteristics: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }

    //used to identify what is inside the charateristics
    characteristicValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@" String Characteristic Value %@", characteristicValue);
   //characteristicData = [characteristicValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if([characteristicValue length] != 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Length Characteristic Value %lu", [characteristicValue length]);

        int indexf =    1;
        int indexs =    2;
        int indext =    3;
        int indexft =   4;
        //int indexfft =  5;

        firstCharacter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [characteristicValue characterAtIndex:indexf-1]];
        secondCharacter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [characteristicValue characterAtIndex:indexs-1]];
        thirdCharacter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [characteristicValue characterAtIndex:indext-1]];
        fourthCharacter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [characteristicValue characterAtIndex:indexft-1]];
        //fifthCharacter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [characteristicValue characterAtIndex:indexfft-1]];
        NSLog(@"the ahcoha;fa %@", firstCharacter);
        NSLog(@"the ahcoha;fa %@", secondCharacter);
        NSLog(@"the ahcoha;fa %@", thirdCharacter);
        NSLog(@"the ahcoha;fa %@", fourthCharacter);
        NSLog(@"the ahcoha;fa %@", fifthCharacter);

        //for lock/unlock
        if ([thirdCharacter isEqualToString:@"0"])
        {
            UIImage *lockDoorImage =[UIImage imageNamed: @"btn_lock_mode.png"];
            [self.btnDoorImage setImage: lockDoorImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            NSLog(@"Lock daw");
        }
        else if ([thirdCharacter isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            UIImage *lockDoorImage =[UIImage imageNamed: @"btn_unlock_mode.png"];
            [self.btnDoorImage setImage: lockDoorImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            NSLog(@"unLock daw");
        }

        //for on/off alarm
        if ([fourthCharacter isEqualToString:@"0"])
        {
            UIImage *lockDoorImage =[UIImage imageNamed: @"btn_toggle_off.png"];
            [self.btnAlarmImage setImage: lockDoorImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            NSLog(@"alarm off daw");
        }
        else if ([fourthCharacter isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            UIImage *lockDoorImage =[UIImage imageNamed: @"btn_toggle_on.png"];
            [self.btnAlarmImage setImage: lockDoorImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            NSLog(@"alarm on daw");
        }

        //for active/inactive sensor
        if([secondCharacter isEqualToString:@"0"])
        {
            _LabelsensorStatus.text = @"Active";

        }
        else if ([secondCharacter isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            _LabelsensorStatus.text = @"Inactive";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"alknbfjasd");
    }



    // Have we got everything we need?
     //We have, so show the data,

    if (characteristic.value != nil )
    {
        //value here.
        NSLog(@"chahahaha %@", characteristic.value);

        if([buttonClicked isEqualToString:@"open"])
        {
            doorValue = @"I:A:1\n";
            NSLog(@"You cliked Open Door button: %@", doorValue);

        }
        else if ([buttonClicked isEqualToString:@"close"])
        {
            doorValue = @"I:A:0\n";
            NSLog(@"You cliked Close Door button: %@", doorValue);
        }


        if([buttonClicked isEqualToString:@"on"])
        {
            doorValue = @"I:B:1\n";
            NSLog(@"You cliked alarm on button: %@", doorValue);
        }

        else if ([buttonClicked isEqualToString:@"off"])
        {
            doorValue = @"I:B:0\n";
            NSLog(@"You cliked alarm Off button: %@", doorValue);
        }


        if([buttonClicked isEqualToString:@"Active"])
        {
            doorValue = @"I:S:0\n";
        }
        else if ([buttonClicked isEqualToString:@"Inactive"])
        {
            doorValue = @"I:S:1\n";
        }
    }

//    //doorValue = @"I:A:1";
    NSLog(@"\nDoor Value used: %@", doorValue);

    payload = [doorValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"payload2 %@", payload);

    NSLog(@"Connected to peripheral %@", peripheral);

    //tempVariable


    if(buttonClicked != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"ButtonClicked is not nil");
        if ((characteristic.properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse))
        {
            NSLog(@"Writing is possible");
            [peripheral writeValue:payload forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];
            payloadValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:payload encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            newCharacteristicValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"newCharacteristicValueaa = %@", newCharacteristicValue);

            NSLog(@"charot  %@ ",  newCharacteristicValue);
            NSLog(@"payload  %@ ",  payloadValue);

            NSLog(@"newCharacteristicValue = %@", newCharacteristicValue);
        }

        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Writing is not possible");
        }
    }

    // Cancel our subscription to the characteristic+
    [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic]; //Jong (NO to YES)

    // and disconnect from the peripheral
   // [self.centralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:peripheral];

    // Otherwise, just add the data on to what we already have
    [_data appendData:payload];


    doorValue = nil;
}
```

Comment: Try dispatching your updates to the button images on the main queue. Updating from a background queue will cause delays.

Comment: How? can you explain sir?

Comment: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           [self.btnAlarmImage setImage: lockDoorImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        });`

Comment: i'm not familiar in this type of code sir ,anyway thank you. but can you please help me how can i apply that in my codeS?

Comment: Put that block of code where you are currently setting the button image.  It dispatches the block onto the main queue.  All UI updates must happen on the main queue

Comment: if (button.selected)
    {
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_unlock_mode.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_unlock_mode.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];});

Comment: is this is correct?

Comment: `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` will be called from a background thread, so when you call `[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_unlock_mode.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];` it will be called from a background thread; this is not permitted and causes delays.  You need to wrap all UI updates in ` dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` as I showed in my comment, not just the button but other UI updates such as `_LabelsensorStatus.text`

Comment: okay sir, thank you for this, i will try later.

Comment: sir, it is same as before.

Comment: sir, i just fixed the delay , button having a problem in sending I:B:0 and I:B:1 in peripheral

Comment: in sending I:A:0\n and I:A:1\n it works smoothly but sending I:B:0\n and I:B:1\n, stop on second send of data